# php curl behaves differently under browser & CLI due to proxy

Tags: php, curl, proxy

Initially I was having issues trying to figure out why php curl under browser behaves differently when I tried to execute the same script by CLI.

By turning on the CURLOPT_VERBOSE with log output and compare the result of the CLI and browser, here are the differences I've seen:

**CURL Under CLI**

```
* About to connect() to proxy localhost port 3128 (#4)
*   Trying ::1...
* Connection refused
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 3128 (#4)
* Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to someurl.com:443
* Server auth using Basic with user 'some_username'
> CONNECT someurl.com:443 HTTP/1.1
Host: someurl.com:443
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive

< HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required
< Mime-Version: 1.0
< Date: Fri, 11 Dec 2020 12:04:46 CST
< Via: 1.1 someotherurl.com:8080 (Cisco-WSA/12.0.1-334)
< Content-Type: text/html
< Connection: close
< Proxy-Connection: close
< Content-Length: 2109
< X-RBT-SCAR: 2.3.4.5:11517381:2000
< Proxy-Authenticate: Basic realm="Cntlm for parent"
* Authentication problem. Ignoring this.
< 
* Received HTTP code 407 from proxy after CONNECT
* Connection #4 to host localhost left intact
```

**CURL Under Browser**

```
* About to connect() to someurl.com port 443 (#6)
*   Trying 1.2.3.4...
* Connected to someurl.com (1.2.3.4) port 443 (#6)
* warning: ignoring value of ssl.verifyhost
* skipping SSL peer certificate verification
* SSL connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* Server certificate:
*   subject: C=US,ST=FL,L=Boca Raton,O=Telit IoT Platforms,OU=secureWISE,CN=someurl.com
*   start date: Apr 15 21:18:15 2020 GMT
*   expire date: May 15 21:18:15 2022 GMT
*   common name: someurl.com
*   issuer: E=support@securewise.net,CN=secureWISE CA-256,OU=SecureWISE Certificate Authority,O=ILS Technology LLC,O=Telit Wireless Solutions Inc,L=Boca Raton,ST=Florida,C=US
* Server auth using Basic with user 'some_username'
> GET /someurl HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic SomeAuthKey
Host: someurl.com
Accept: */*

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Fri, 11 Dec 2020 04:07:40 GMT
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< X-Powered-By: Undertow/1
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=c2BBPwZBjGxCaH5om6unoKaI; path=/
< Set-Cookie: somekey=somevalue; path=/
< Content-Type: text/xml
< Content-Length: 125291
< Content-disposition: attachment; filename=somefilename.xml
< Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
< SWOrigin: sw_proxy
< Connection: close
< 
* Closing connection 6
```

My initial hunch is that this has something to do with proxy (as this PC does use a proxy to go online)

And looking at the browser log, it seems as if proxy was skipped.

I've also checked the phpinfo() for both the browser and CLI, and I can see that there's `proxy`, `http_proxy`, `https_proxy` defined in the environment variables, as well as under `$_SERVER` for **CLI**, but **not on browser**, which makes me believe more that my assumption is correct.

So in order to combat this, I've tried adding the following code before the curl call:

```
        if(isset($_SERVER['http_proxy']))
            unset($_SERVER['http_proxy']);       
        if (isset($_SERVER['https_proxy']))
            unset($_SERVER['https_proxy']);
        if (isset($_SERVER['proxy']))
            unset($_SERVER['proxy']);

        if(isset($_ENV['http_proxy']))
            unset($_ENV['http_proxy']);       
        if (isset($_ENV['https_proxy']))
            unset($_ENV['https_proxy']);
        if (isset($_ENV['proxy']))
            unset($_ENV['proxy']);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $target_url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "someuser:somepass");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
        $result = curl_exec($ch); 
        curl_close($ch);
```

But the verbose still shows that it still tries to go through the proxy when executed under CLI.

Any suggestion on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging around, it turns out all I had to do was to by pass the someurl.com in the /etc/cntlm.conf by including the url in the NoProxy config.